# cannot understand error call not allowed with $http call (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have this error with a DELETE call with $http :

> DELETE
>   'url'/?$$hashKey=021&id=2&idHike=2&label=pelle&onMe=true&weight=110
>        405 (Method Not Allowed)

If anyone can help...

Frontend:

```
$scope.delete = function (item) {
            var config = {
                params: item
            };

            $http.delete("/rest/items/deleteFromHike/", config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config)
            {
                $log.info("SUCCESS");
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config)
            {
                $log.info("ERROR");
            });

        };
```

Backend (JAVA) :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/items/deleteFromHike/{itemDto}",
            method = RequestMethod.DELETE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public void deleteItemFromHike(@PathVariable ItemDTO itemDto) {
        log.debug("REST request to delete Item : {}", itemDto.toString());
    }
```

Comment: not a solution to your problem, but a URL must never contain both the words "rest" and "delete" - this isn't RESTful at all. It should rather be something like `DELETE /rest/hikes/{hikeId}/items/{itemId}`. If you put a verb into the URL, you're doing RPC...

Comment: We encounter a problem where Rails doesn't support Body in delete with Restangular https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/78#issuecomment-18687759

I know it's a bit far away from your configuration but maybe it can give a clue

Comment: I am a bit confused about the syntax to use for an angularjs delete $http call with two parameters (here : idItem and idHike)

Answer (score 0):

Probably a configuration issue with your web server. You might have to explicitly configure which HTTP VERBS are accepted.